# date() function outputting wrong result - PHP

Tags: php, date, epoch

Here's what i did -:

1. Generated the UNIX_TIMESTAMP result in mysql. It came out
   `1360756718` seconds.
2. Since I am in GMT +5.30, got the number of seconds in 5 hrs and 30 mins. Result was `19800` seconds
3. Ran this function -> date('j M Y H:i:s',(1360756718+19800)).

But unfortunately, the answer was `1 hour` ahead of original time. And I mean exactly `1 hour`. Result was `13 Feb 2013 18:28:38` which should have been `13 Feb 2013 17:28:38`.

Where am I worng?

Comment: Do you have the correct timezone settings in you MySQL database and in you PHP configuration?

Comment: What does [date_timezone_get()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimezone.php) return, and what's your real timezone?

Comment: date_default_timezone_get() returns `Europe/Berlin`. Mine is `Asia/Kolkata`. But how does it matter, since i am doing this on unix timestamp.

Comment: You're converting a Unix timestamp to a date string using [date()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), which is probably changing your timestamp with the correct timezone.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you are in +5:30 but with daylight savings time, we still are 1 hour back. so you now are only +4:30

Comment: can you explain in a bit more detail

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php, Here you can see all that the the date() function has to offer. There is a `I` argument that can tell you if the date is in daylight savings time or not. If it is, you add another hour to the result.

Comment: I can't find the `I` argument

Comment: ahm...on the parameter table, there is an entire section dedicated to Timezone. The second one is I (capital i). Just search daylight on the page and you'll find it. There are also some examples with maketime that might solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

I think your timezone is set incorrectly. You need to dig around your Apache/PHP/Mysql settings to find out what it is set to.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo date( 'd.m.Y H:i:s', '1360756718' ); // 13.02.2013 13:58:38
echo date( 'd.m.Y H:i:s',  ( '1360756718'+19800 ) ); // 13.02.2013 19:28:38
```

For me this came out as planned. Are you sure that you started with the right time? As some already mentioned, the problem most likely lies in your timezone or daylight savings time.

Comment: shouldn't your result be `13.02.2013 17:28:38`. I thins i am messing around with date() functions. Please can anyone explain it

Comment: `13 + 5 = 18` ... `58 + 30 = 1:28` ... `18 + 1:28 = 19:28`

Answer (score 1):

Please check your current timezone first.
[Here you can check all supported timezones as well](http://php.net/timezones)

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding:

```
ini_set('date.timezone', 'My/Timezone');
```

Since php 5.1 it's also possible to do:

```
date_default_timezone_set ( string $timezone_identifier )
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

To set the time to your own timezone. The timezones that are available for php are here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Answer (score 0):

the other answers say you should check and correct your timezone settings.
I would do that because it's more correct (regarding to daylight saving time and so on).

If you want to have the easy way try gmdate function:

```
string gmdate ( string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ] )
```

This one will always calculate in GMT - you don't have to check the server settings.
(However it will ignore Daylight Saving Time too.)